# failed to mount a network drive to vbox using sshfs

Tags: ssh, vagrant, sshfs

Tried to use sshfs to map a network drive to vbox started by vagrant.  I cooked up the following command but it failed.  Any idea why?   The OS running in vbox is FC20. I can ssh into it fine.

```
$ sshfs -p 2222 -o Compression=yes -o DSAAuthentication=yes -o LogLevel=FATAL -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /Users/user1/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1: fs

fuse: mount point is not a directory `/Users/jqian/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Found a temporary workaround:

ssh into the box and set the a password for the user "vagrant".

```
sshfs -p 2222 vagrant@localhost:  <dir_to_mount>
```

I created a directory called "fs" in my local, so I can just run it as

```
sshfs -p 2222 vagrant@localhost: /home/tester/fs
```